# Can't create a project

Tags: twitter

I’m trying to create a new project and I see the message:

> Your changes couldn’t be saved.
>
> ```
> You have already applied for this type of access. You may apply for each level of access a maximum of one time.
> ```

Here is the screen:
[image]

So what is the problem and how to create an app for cross-posting into tweeter account?

Answer (score 0):

It might be because that name is chosen already. Choose a unique name.